# how to interprete the ACF/PACF plots?

Tags: modeling, econometrics, eviews

what the result suggests of the order of the ARMA model?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to our site. Your question already has answers here: please follow the links from [this search](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=pacf+time+series+order).